# My program only returns the days of a non-leap year Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

fun main(args: Array) {

```
println("Year")
val year = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
var leap = false
println("Month:")
val month = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
if (year % 4 == 0) {
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        leap = year % 400 == 0
    } else
        leap = true
    val numDay = when (month){
        1 ->"31"
        2 ->"29"
        3 ->"31"
        4 ->"30"
        5 ->"31"
        6 ->"30"
        7 ->"31"
        8 ->"31"
        9 ->"30"
        10 ->"31"
        11 ->"30"
        12 ->"31"
        else ->"Invalid Argument"
    }
```

> I can't read the numDay of a leap year

```
} else
    leap = false
val numDay = when (month){
    1 ->"31"
    2 ->"28"
    3 ->"31"
    4 ->"30"
    5 ->"31"
    6 ->"30"
    7 ->"31"
    8 ->"30"
    9 ->"31"
    10 ->"30"
    11 ->"31"
    12 ->"30"
    else ->"Invalid Argument"
}
println(if (leap) "$year is a leap year." else "$year is not a leap year.")
println("The number of day is $numDay")
```

}

> only return the number of days of a non-leap year

[the number of days should be 30 but always read the number of a non leap year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NKVZ.png)

Comment: You typed the values in your when statement wrong. It says month 11 has 31 days, for example. November has 30 days. Anyway, your problem is that you define `numDay` inside each `else` block so it has scope limited to inside the block.

Comment: I guess this is a programming exercise? In production code, it's far better (simpler, more likely to be correct, shorter, more maintainable, more likely to cope with corner cases) to **use a library** — and Kotlin has many library classes for handling all sorts of date/time calculations; there's no need to write your own. ([Obligatory Tom Scott video](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY).)

Comment: Yes gidds this is a exercise that i'm solving to train for the test. The test is on paper without computer so i cant use librarians

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate calculations from input (readln) and output (println). The calculations for *isLeapYear* and *numDays* could be in functions:

```
fun isLeapYear(year: Int): Boolean {
  return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
}

fun numDays(isLeapYear: Boolean, month: Int): Any {
  if (isLeapYear) {
    return listOf(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31).getOrElse(month - 1) { "Invalid argument" }
  } else {
    return listOf(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31).getOrElse(month - 1) { "Invalid argument" }
  }
}

println("Year")
val year = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
println("Month:")
val month = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: 0

val isLeapYear = isLeapYear(year)
val numDay = numDays(isLeapYear, month)

println(if (isLeapYear) "$year is a leap year." else "$year is not a leap year.")
println("The number of day is $numDay")
```

That way the calculations are more readable and shorter.